# Possible bug in `typesafe-actions` module for TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, typesafe-actions

I started migration from `JavaScript React` project into `TypeScript React`. I am using Redux and Sagas for my store and side-effects handling.

I discovered one problem what I cannot explain by myself. Module `typesafe-actions` include API for [creating typed reducers](https://github.com/piotrwitek/typesafe-actions#reducer-creators-api) easily.

Let's see this examples of same reducer, but written in different way:

```
// This reducer works as expected
const reducer = createReducer<IState, RootAction>(initialState).handleAction(
  fetchProfileAsync.success,
  (state, action) => {
    return {
      ...state,
      profile: action.payload,
    };
  }
);

// This reducer have TypeScript errors:
const reducer = createReducer<IState, RootAction>(initialState).handleType(
  EActionTypes.FETCH_PROFILE_SUCCESS,
  (state, action) => {
    return {
      ...state,
      profile: action.payload,
    };
  }
);
```

In second example, `action` variable is typed as:

```
action: {type: EActionTypes.FETCH_PROFILE_SUCCESS;payload: {}; } | PayloadAction<EActionTypes.FETCH_PROFILE_SUCCESS, IUser
```

This is my definition of this action:

```
export const fetchProfileAsync = createAsyncAction(
  EActionTypes.FETCH_PROFILE_REQUEST,
  EActionTypes.FETCH_PROFILE_SUCCESS,
  EActionTypes.FETCH_PROFILE_FAILURE
)<undefined, IUser, Error>();
```

Why `action` variable can be `IUser` OR `{}` in second example whenI not defined it like that?

It works fine when I not use `handleType`, but `handleAction`